# Copy a file to server with a different filename using Python Paramiko over ssh/sftp

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, file-transfer, file-copying

I have `c:\file_a.txt` which I would like to copy to `/home/the_user/file_b.txt`. If the remote file exists already, replace it, if not, create it.

Here is my code:

```py
import json
import paramiko
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from os import getenv
from os.path import join, dirname, expanduser

if __name__ == "__main__":
    load_dotenv(join(dirname(__file__), ".env"))
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.load_host_keys(expanduser(join("~", ".ssh", "known_hosts")))
    ssh.connect(getenv("SSH_SERVER"), username=getenv("SSH_USER"), \
       password=getenv("SSH_PWD"), key_filename=getenv("SSH_KEY"))
    sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
    sftp.put("c:\file_a.txt", "/home/the_user/")
    # my understanding is putting a file to a folder sets the working directory to that folder
    sftp.rename("file_a.txt", "file_b.txt")
    sftp.remove("file_a.txt")
    sftp.close()
    ssh.close()
```

But I am getting a `Failure` error on the rename. Feels like I am missing something obvious and would appreciate any pointers.

How can I copy a local file to a remote file with a different filename over ssh/sftp/scp using the `paramiko` library in `Python`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So upload the file straight to the new name:

```
sftp.put("c:\file_a.txt", "/home/the_user/file_b.txt")
```