# How to rewrite content of a file on SSH server with Python Paramiko?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, overwrite

I am using Python Paramiko to connect to SSH server, I need to overwrite the contents of the `file`. The new content to write to the file is in the `new_content` variable. How can i do this?

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=host, username=user, password=secret, port=port, look_for_keys=False)

new_content = 'content'


def sendCommand(comand):
    print("Sending command")

    if (client):
        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(comand)

        while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
            if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
                alldata = stdout.channel.recv(1024)
                while stdout.channel.recv_ready():
                    alldata += stdout.channel.recv(1024)

                print(str(alldata, "utf8"))

sendCommand('export PATH="${HOME}/.fuelup/bin:${PATH}" && mkdir fuel-project && cd fuel-project && forc new counter-contract')
```

After that I open the `file` to be rewritten:

```
sendCommand('vim counter-contract/src/main.sw')
```

Comment: vim expects to be connected to an interactive terminal - it would likely be much easier to overwrite the file using a command like `cat > counter-contract/src/main.sw`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy a file to server with a different filename using Python Paramiko over ssh/sftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63411486/copy-a-file-to-server-with-a-different-filename-using-python-paramiko-over-ssh-s)

Comment: @NickODell Please tell me more about this method, I'm just learning Python and Paramiko is completely new for me

Comment: I found what you were talking about, now it's not clear how to press Ctrl + D in Paramiko to exit the editor

Comment: Ctrl-D sends EOF. How to send EOF in paramiko: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554292/how-to-send-eof-to-stdin-in-paramiko

Answer (score 0):

As a result, I solved the problem with this method

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=host, username=user, password=secret, port=port, look_for_keys=False)

new_content = 'content'

    ftp = ssh.open_sftp()
    my_file = ftp.file('/root/path/to/file', 'w')  # 'w' will open the file for editing - it will truncate whatever was there before
    my_file.write(f'{new_content}') # write whatever you wish to the file
    my_file.flush()
    ftp.close()
```